# C++ Generic command parser using variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write some sort of command handler, which can tokenize an istringstream, automatically convert the tokens into variables of specific types and call a callback function with the converted variables as arguments. Here is simplified version of my code:

```
void Callback(int x, char y, float z) {
  // do whatever
  // note: For simplicity, I use a callback with a fixed signature
  //       here. In my actual implementation, the callback can be
  //       called with any number and types of arguments - but that
  //       I have solved already.
}

template<typename T>
T GetNextArgument(std::istringstream& strm) {
  // get one token from the input stream and convert it to the required type
  T val;
  strm >> val;
  return val;
}

template<typename ...Args>
void ParseAndExecute(std::istringstream& input_stream) {
  Callback(GetNextArgument<Args>(input_stream)...);
}

int main() {
  std::istringstream strm("15 a 17.3");
  ParseAndExecute(strm);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem I have is that the `ParseAndExecute()` function after parameter pack expansion looks like this:

```
void ParseAndExecute(std::istringstream& strm) {
  Callback(GetNextArgument<int>(strm), 
           GetNextArgument<char>(strm),
           GetNextArgument<float>(strm));
}
```

Since the order of evaluation of the arguments is not defined, the tokens may be taken from the stream in incorrect order (and in my case, they always are). Instead I would need the expansion to give me something more like that:

```
void ParseAndExecute(std::istringstream& strm) {
  int a1 = GetNextArgument<int>(strm);
  char a2 = GetNextArgument<char>(strm);
  float a3 = GetNextArgument<float>(strm);
  Callback(a1, a2, a3);
}
```

But I cannot see how to achieve that with parameter pack expansion. Maybe with a recursive template...? Or do you have any other suggestion to achieve a similar functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Caller {
    template<class...Args>
    Caller(Args&&... args) { Callback(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};

template<typename ...Args>
void ParseAndExecute(std::istringstream& input_stream) {
  Caller{GetNextArgument<Args>(input_stream)...};
}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked out of the box! But...why? Is the order of evaluation fixed for the constructor? Or is it because of using the braces instead of parenthesis?

Comment: @GeorgP. It's the curly braces. A _braced-init-list_ always guarantees left-to-right evaluation of its elements.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an intermediate `std::tuple` with [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) because left-to-right order is mandatory in this case:

```
std::tuple<Args...> tuple_args = {GetNextArgument<Args>(input_stream)... };
std::apply([](auto&&... args) { 
    Callback(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)... );
 }, std::move(tuple_args));
```

You have to use a lambda if `Callback` does not have a fixed signature as you mentioned and you want to rely on deduction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to get this to work. First problem is that `std::apply()` is C++17, while I only have C++14. So I'm using `std::experimental::apply()`. Next, I'm a bit confused with the many uses of `args`. It's not the same in all 4 cases, right?

Comment: Then I get an error `parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’`. Shouldn't it be `Callback(args...)` inside the lambda?

Comment: @GeorgP. You can find implementation of `std::apply` that are quite easy to write if you need them. I have renamed `args` (you have the tuple containing the args, and the arguments of the lambda), and I have added the missing expansion inside the lambda. In the end you should probably use T.C. solution because it does not involves storing the arguments in an intermediate struct.